# android studios unable to find R. resources, and App header lacking proper formatting

Tags: java, xml, user-interface, android-studio, gradle

I am attempting to create a calculator, up until 30 minutes ago, my code was compiling normally, but randomly, R. resources are no longer found ([R.resources not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MO5sJ.png)) and the header for my app is a grey rectangle ([grey rectangle app header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T39mG.png)) instead of an orange header that says the name of my app. I have already attempted to clean the project but this fails because it is unable to read android manifest.xml (will post screenshot in comments, I can only post 2 links because of my reputation). Is their a way to fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZRzs.png (androidmanifest.xml unable to be read error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check all your layout xml files. I think the problem lies in one of your layout files , you recently modified .

Android Studio checks all your xml files  first and then your java files and after that indexes your Resource files ( R.something.something).

Because there is an error in code of one of your xml file ,Android Studio is not able to proceed to the next step( ie. Indexing Resources), due to which it is unable to find Resources and showing R.something.something in red text.

To solve this problem follow these steps:

1. Check for Red Marks in layout files you recently modified ,and rectify the errors if any.

   **In your case undo all the changes made in AndroidManifest.xml**
2. Clean build your Project.
3. Run the application .

If the problem still persists , post the error logs that are visible in your android Monitor Console, so that I have a deeper understanding of the issue.

Hope this Helps :)